# Gnome 14.10 memory leak, over 5gb of gnome-shell

Tags: gnome, swap, memory-leak

I am experiencing a pretty huge memory leak from gnome-shell and after a while memory is up to over 5GB. I have 8GB of system memory and when the system starts using swap the whole system slows down a lot. I do have a SSD but that doesn't make matters better. I have changed the swap settings to 1 but that has no effect. I regularly kill gnome-shell off to be able to use the system. I came from Unity where system-ram was used quite heavily and swap was sometimes used as well. My solution was to up ram from 4GB to 8GB and to change to GNOME, but it seems I still have the same problem :-(

Any ideas how to limit gnome-shell ram usage? Any program that can kill off gnome when it exceeds 4GB for example? I don't really know what to do except try Unity again or change to Xubuntu or such. I do really like GNOME though...

Comment: A have a couple of scripts which clear the cache, and push swap back onto disk.  If you would like to try them I can post them into an answer.

Comment: Please post more information on your memory use. output of `free -m`. top can also help. Linux is not windows and unused RAM is wasted RAM. Hard to know if you even have a problem. Clearing the cache and pushing swap back to disk may or may not help.

Comment: here is my free -m output:
 total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7967       7555        412         43         33       2739
-/+ buffers/cache:       4781       3185
Swap:         3813        588       3225

Comment: I prefer the system not to use swap completely as it uses the ssd to much and it only makes the system slower. It is a bit annoying that it is so hard to stop the system from using it. I do want to be able to put the computer to sleep :-)

Comment: For the close voters: I think that this is fully in topic with the Gnome flavor of Ubuntu.

Comment: This is still relevant. Gnome shell leaks memory, in current LTS also, often due to some (badly written) extension. So I think it's worth keeping this open.

Comment: It's still a bug, no? Although it appears it doesn't happen when using intel video drivers... Perhaps this is only an [NVIDIA issue?](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/879616/memory-leak-for-gnome-shell-for-gdm-user-all-driver-versions-/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`gnome-shell` leaks memory like a colander.

There is a bug reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/930402) (it's for Mint but it's the same problem) and [on redhat](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=977387).

Upstream there are [at least 9 bugs reported](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=gnome-shell%20memory%20leak).

Basically (one developer told me once, I can't find the reference) gnome-shell is completely unable (by design) to control the memory usage of its extensions. Add this to the fact that there is no API documentation for writing them (at least, I could not find it when I wrote [mine](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/827/switch-focus-type/)) and well... leak happens.

In my case, I had to remove a couple of extensions (sensors and weather were the main culprits) that made the shell grows like crazy. Even now, every now and then I have to restart the shell with <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> and `r` to get it back to its normal size (and then you have to cope with [gnome-terminals going crazy](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=730261)...).

Practical solution:

1. remove all extensions, look at the memory usage, and add them one by one to find the worst offender(s).
2. `gnome-shell` still leaks memory by itself, or you really need some extensions. So I do every now and then (basically every morning, my PC is normally on 24/7):
3. kill gnome terminals to avoid the bug above (in 14.04-shell 3.10; should be fixed in newer shell), by doing from one of them:

   ```
   killall gnome-terminal
   ```

   and reset the shell with <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> and `r`

PD: I know, there are others DEs. But I like `gnome-shell`, call me crazy...

Comment: I might need to take away an extension. I tried a extension that monitors temperature but i didnt get it to work anyways...I would be great if it were that simple!

I really like the simplicity of gnome instead of unity :-P

Comment: i unistalled a few gnome programs to lessen the memory, now it is only up to 3gb. I will see tomorrow if it helped. I also disabled the firefox-ubuntu-addon inside firefox. I hope this helps :-)

Comment: didnt seem to work....3.6gb and climbing :-(

Comment: Up to 6.1gb now....This does not feel normal. It is a very fresh install with very little tinkering done to the system.

Comment: Try to remove *all* extensions and repeat. If still there, it is probably something introduced in 14.10 --- so a bug report would be the right way. I have no intention to upgrade now... I have work to do ;-)

Comment: It seems that the removal of extensions seemed to work after i rebooted :-) Now it is stable on 2.3gb. Thanks for the help!!!!

Comment: Yep. This is the same for me. It would be nice to build a list of "safe" extensions... if you think the question is answered, please mark it so. http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Note to @korc about your suggested script to automate this (in edit): restarting the shell and killing the terminals can be disruptive of what you're doing, and cause data loss if done at the wrong time. So I think it's basically a manual thing...

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04.2, `$ killall gnome-terminal' gives `gnome-terminal: no process found`. Memory usage is increasing rapidly. Any update?

Comment: @XiaodongQi, if you have no terminals running, simply skip the step. The trick here is to find which extension (if any) is creating the leak. Use `gnome-tweak-tool` to see which extensions are loaded, and explore from there. In my 16.04.2 gnome-shell is quite usable, barring the sporadic crash-and-restart.