# Ubuntu 15.10 Gnome works laggy!

Tags: gnome, 15.10, ubuntu-gnome

After using Ubuntu 15.10 Gnome for a few hours, it starts to work laggy. Restarting Gnome with `alt+F2+R` solves the problem, but it happens again and getting worse unless I restart the gnome.

I have clean installed Ubuntu 15.10 Gnome, but it didn't solve the problem either. I didn't have this problem in Ubuntu 15.04.

Does anyone know what is the reason for that and how can I solve it?

P.S My laptop is Lenovo Ideapad Yoga 13 (CPU: Core i5 3rd generation, Ram: 4gb; VGA: Intel HD 4000 )

[Current memory usage of the system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDgcW.png)

```
top - 01:24:35 up 11:54,  3 users,  load average: 0.35, 0.52, 0.59
Tasks: 240 total,   1 running, 239 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  7.3 us,  2.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 89.8 id,  0.3 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   3926284 total,  3857168 used,    69116 free,    13596 buffers
KiB Swap:  7999484 total,  2480416 used,  5519068 free.   569548 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                              
 1397 ko        20   0 1911828 181784  29928 S   8.0  4.6  67:43.24 gnome-shell                          
 1915 ko        20   0 2625444 196152   8088 S   7.3  5.0  29:55.51 WebKitPluginPro                      
 1239 root      20   0  526364  72128  57088 S   7.0  1.8  20:16.12 Xorg                                 
23130 ko        20   0  454968  27960  19428 S   5.0  0.7   0:06.27 gnome-terminal-                      
 1375 ko         9 -11  585068   7044   4296 S   4.0  0.2  28:47.54 pulseaudio                           
 1868 ko        20   0 4471816 404008  25276 S   4.0 10.3  14:32.91 WebKitWebProces                      
22755 ko        20   0  532612  31220  14512 S   2.3  0.8   0:30.63 gnome-system-mo                      
 1979 ko        20   0 1426564 209216  50336 S   2.0  5.3  27:16.48 chrome                               
 2105 ko        20   0  966080  77724  17408 S   2.0  2.0  13:04.47 chrome                               
  716 root      20   0  193312    104      0 S   0.7  0.0   4:27.65 teamviewerd                          
21948 ko        20   0 1547872 423168  70676 S   0.7 10.8   3:05.17 chrome                               
22925 ko        20   0 1315524 333220 107304 S   0.7  8.5   0:47.89 chrome                               
23258 ko        20   0   29348   2956   2328 R   0.7  0.1   0:02.34 top                                  
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0   0:51.91 rcu_sched                            
   18 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0   0:05.76 rcuos/1                              
  186 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0   0:00.73 kworker/1:1H                         
 7464 ko        20   0  628496  19060  12228 S   0.3  0.5   0:04.23 gjs                                  
11796 ko        20   0 1188848  64252  21028 S   0.3  1.6   0:21.68 chrome                               
21761 ko        20   0  951588 167760  53004 S   0.3  4.3   0:13.68 chrome                               
21787 ko        20   0 1679864 219356  52188 S   0.3  5.6   0:15.42 chrome
```

Result from `free -m`:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3834       3775         59        399         13        611
-/+ buffers/cache:       3150        683
Swap:         7811       2441       5370
```

Comment: Open System Monitor and sort by highest RAM usage. Take a screenshot and post it here. If you need help getting to that point, just leave a comment.

Comment: @Zacharee1 I have added the screenshot. Please check the updated question.  Thanks!

Comment: Hmm. Can you run `top` in a terminal and post the output in your question? (People here seem to prefer that you copy and paste that one, so I'll recommend you do that ;)).

Comment: `ctrl` + `shift` + `c` to copy the text you select in the terminal.

Comment: @Zacharee1 copy and pasting from terminal doesn't seem quite readable even thought I have add it as a code. So I have added a screenshot again. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I think I can fix that.

Comment: Wait, what does not readable mean?

Comment: Ugh, sorry. I meant to ask for `free -m`.

Comment: @Zacharee1 please check the question

Comment: I'm assuming that the computer hasn't been running very long. You only have 4GB of RAM, which isn't too much. Right now, it looks like you have less than 700MB RAM free. That could be the problem. As more processes open, and others run longer, more RAM is getting used up. I think the problem is just that you are running low on RAM.

Comment: Ignore the comment I deleted. I'm being stupid today :p.

Comment: Here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/557088/gnome-14-10-memory-leak-over-5gb-of-gnome-shell