# What's eating all the RAM and swap?

Tags: games, swap, 16.10

After some hours after playing Minecraft or another game in 16.10, all the RAM and swap gets filled by an invisible process, and the system freezes with HDD LED on, so it's writing something to the SSD, but nothing happens, and I need to force shutdown and then restart the computer.

To understand these issues, refer to the below screenshots.

[image: pic 1]

[image: pic 2]

Here are two screenshots without Chrome and Java, adding the values on the first picture, it's not 1.7GB. I think some hidden process causes this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You don't have much RAM (2GB?) and play Minecraft. That explains everything. Try to use oracle java 8, Minecraft tends to create memory leaks with openjdk.

Comment: It has 4GB, and 4GB swap, java version is: 

`java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)`

Under OS X and Windows, i had no problems like this... :/

Comment: Your problem is a memory leak of some kind: RAM gets fuller and fuller until is is swapped to disk and also the swap partition is full, then your Desktop freezes cause you are out of memory and swap. Your goal should be to find out which program is creating a memory leak , why and fix it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143791/how-do-i-find-which-process-is-leaking-memory

Comment: Yes, i know this... But can't find it, see first picture, all of the processes RAM usage is not 8gb, java is 1.3gb, chrome is 600-700mb, and where is the more 6gb?

Comment: @USPSend: Please read the full texts on answers and try to understand them, ask if you don't. This is the vital part for you: "Select View - All Processes, go to Edit - Preferences and enable Virtual Memory column." , you get an extra column, showing the virtual memory a process uses, take alook at my system monitor where I did this: http://imgur.com/a/29PSj

Comment: @mondjunge Thanks, looks like gnome-shell does it. http://imgur.com/a/jE1Tj

Comment: I found an answer that's linking gnome shell memory leaks to extensions. Try to disable gnome-shell extensions you installed until you find the one that creates the memory leak. http://askubuntu.com/questions/557088/gnome-14-10-memory-leak-over-5gb-of-gnome-shell

Comment: Run `top -o %MEM` in a terminal - does it give any other info as to what is using memory ? Minecraft has a tendency to use more and more memory over time - maybe just quit and reopen it from time to time ?

Comment: @JonasCz Looks like java does it, but on OS X and Windows, that was not problem... But Minecraft ingame shows 300mb, top command 5gb, what the hell?

Comment: Minecraft is sometimes just buggy, maybe that's why it shows you 300mb - make sure you have the latest version of both Java & the game.  What graphics card & graphics drivers are you using ?

Comment: Intel HD3000 with default drivers, 60+ fps everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Chrome can use a lot of RAM

When Chrome window has focus press <kbd>Shift</kbd>>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to bring up process manager:

[image]

I've ententionally narrowed the Task name width to hide my gmail inbox name but you can see it is using over 400 MB of RAM. In this screen Chrome is using **1.7 GB** of RAM simply surfing the net with 10 Tabs opened.

Your screen only shows the `Chrome` name but this screen shows each opened `Tab` name to track down the offender. In my case if I wanted to free up RAM I would close `gamil.com`.

The second large RAM user is `Earth-Sunrise` website that has a comment section. Some websites with comment sections can burn up lots of RAM, in testing over 1 GB per tab over a few hours. Simpy refreshing the Tab brings the usage back down to ~100 MB.

## Display JAVA Memory Usage

The tool VisualVM will display Java memory usage and other information:

[image: Java RAM Usage]

You can download it from github: ([VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/))

Comment: The problem is not chrome, it uses around 600-700mb, java is 1.3gb... I don't know what eaten the more 6gb ram + swap.

Comment: @UDPSend You need VisualVM Java task manager which I've just added to the answer.

Comment: Solved by switching to OpenJDK.

Comment: Glad to hear that pothole on your road to happy computing has been filled. :)