# Why is internet upload so high when I don't actually upload much?

Tags: networking, firefox, google-chrome, monitoring, bandwidth

## Total Monthly Internet Bandwidth

I use `vnstat` to monitor internet usage:

```
$ vnstat

                      rx      /      tx      /     total    /   estimated
 eth0:
       Jul '17    210.70 GiB  /   51.00 GiB  /  261.71 GiB
       Aug '17    275.79 GiB  /   70.54 GiB  /  346.33 GiB  /  348.91 GiB
     yesterday      5.47 GiB  /    2.08 GiB  /    7.55 GiB
         today      2.89 GiB  /    1.36 GiB  /    4.26 GiB  /    5.52 GiB

 wlan0:
       Jul '17         0 KiB  /       0 KiB  /       0 KiB
       Aug '17         0 KiB  /       0 KiB  /       0 KiB  /       0 KiB
     yesterday         0 KiB  /       0 KiB  /       0 KiB
         today         0 KiB  /       0 KiB  /       0 KiB  /      --
```

I switched ISPs 6 months ago and the new ISP is picky on total monthly usage causing me to pay closer attention to stats.

## Real Time Internet Usage

I checked the monitoring options in Ask Ubuntu and the answers point to `nethogs` which only reports KB/Sec by process which is inevitably Firefox or Chrome both reported in KB/Sec:

[image: nethogs]

This isn't helpful because I already know I use Chrome and Firefox. The question is "which tab?" or is it even a tab? Notice there are processes running as `root`? I never use sudo with Chrome or Firefox.

## Investigative 5W's of Data Uploads

There are 5 W's:

- Who is uploading 70 GB of data from my laptop each month? I backup daily to gmail.com which is 5.4 MB of scripts, documents, configuration settings and what not. That's 150 MB per month. Who's grabbing the other 69 GB?
- What program is grabbing this data? I can't use a single process ID for Chrome or Firefox as an answer. I need to know the tab which points to the website. I can't use `root` and some random IP address as an answer.
- Where is this data going? ie IP address.
- When is this happening? Is it when I'm watching a movie? Watching internet news in Al-Jazeera or RT? Some sort of notification bubble on up-load volume would be nice.
- Why? I don't need an answer to that question. The other 4 W's will suffice. It might be Vault 7 or it might not be. You can't sue the CIA and if you can't beat`em you should just block them.

## Daily Internet habits

There are only six things I do daily on the internet:

- Visit Ask Ubuntu and read Q&As. Uploads should be <1 MB/day because any answer I post is < 30 KB or update.
- Watch Al-Jazeera.com live TV which uses HTML5 on youtube.com
- Watch rt.com/on-the-air which uses Flash Player
- Daily backup my scripts, documents and configuration files via e-mail to my gmail.com account and the .tar file is 5.4 MB.
- Watch a movie on random websites in 1080p resolution when lucky, else 480p or 720p when not lucky.
- Google search and visit websites to research Linux/Ubuntu related technical issues.

## Summary

I'm familiar with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> in Chrome to monitor network statistics in real time by Chrome Tab but something that runs in the background collecting statistics is preferable.

I haven't run Windows 8.1 in well over a month so the uploads aren't happening there. It's all in Linux/Ubuntu.

**What can I do to narrow down my searching for the massive uploads?**

Thank you for reading this far.

Comment: I compared your vnstat to mine, and although I have more data, the pattern is roughly the same as yours... so... I'd say yours looks normal. Keep in mind that there's tcp/udp overhead that you're not counting when you add up your raw data totals. It doesn't look like you're bittorrenting, so that's not it. Normal says me.

Comment: ps: it's more accurate to watch the ISP's data usage counter than your own.

Comment: @heynnema  So all the uploading is just acknowledgements of packets received??? The ISP just sent me an email (a few hours ago) saying I'm at 75% of monthly allotment of 450GB for calendar month (which ends in a few hours MST). So it's pretty much on par off the top of my head.

Comment: For many years now, I have run tcpdump on my gateway Ubuntu server that acts as a router/firewall. I keep the raw binary data of every packet coming to and leaving from my local area network for a couple of months. And I keep the processed packets indefinitely, as the raw data becomes overwhelming. The files names are by date and time, and change every 10 minutes. While such a method wouldn't answer some of your questions, it would answer "Where is this data going? ie IP address".

Comment: @DougSmythies That could be very helpful especially if say 50GB+ of the 70GB being uploaded behind my back was going to the same IP address. How would one go about automating tracking Top 10 IP addresses uploaded to and the GB's uploaded?

Comment: I only know how to figure it out as a post-process, meaning I acquire everything and then figure out the top contenders afterwards for some issue. While this is NOT what you need, something like `cut -d" " -f4 tot.txt | sed 's/.[^.]*$//' | sort | uniq -c | sort -g >times.txt` for example gives the histogram of IP addresses (in this example, a previous grep had extracted a sub-set of the original data).

Comment: @DougSmythies I'm not sure I understand but My CPU only runs at 10 to 20% and I was trying to justify buying a 1 to 3 TB hard disk for second drive bay in laptop so would have lots of space for tracking what is leaving my machine. Could you post some sort of answer for what to install, how to turn on the daemon and after that run a daily job to sort through it? I could set it up in cron.

Comment: How I do it is pretty hokey (but good enough for my purposes), and a little labour intensive. Give me some time and I'll write up something.

Comment: You could install `iftop` to help you see the traffic in real time.

Comment: @heynnema I need the opposite because I don't want to sit around staring at real time data. I'd like a daemon to monitor traffic for me.

Comment: Would you like to see the output of my vnstat?

Comment: I was running vnstat `-h` and `-l` this morning before coming to work. I'll play with it more on the weekend. By all means if you have stuff to post in an answer go ahead and I'll be more than happy to upvote right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: This answer only addresses some of the desired "Investigative 5W's of Data Uploads".

Use tcpdump to capture all packet traffic, and use some post-processing to extract desired information.

```
sudo tcpdump -i enp4s0 -w 'ext-%F-%H-%M-%S.bin' -G 3600 -z /home/doug/bin/packet_post_processor2
```

Where:
my WAN facing interface is `enp4s0`;
The file names automatically include the date and time (requires an additional package, but I can not recall which);
I'm asking for file rotation once per hour;
Each file be post processed by the `packet_post_processor` script (2 is for this answer).

The post-processing script:

```sh
#!/bin/dash
#
# packet_post_processor2 Doug Smythies. 2017.09.08
#    Edits as required for updated c prgram, and bad sort order.
#    There may be little use in sort by packets count, but for now
#    it remians.
#
# packet_post_processor2 Doug Smythies. 2017.09.01
#    This script will be called from the always running tcpdump.
#    It is called for every binary file rotation.
#    The purpose is to make summary files of things that one
#    may want to investigate in more detail later on.
#
#    This version is for WinEunuuchs2Unix and
# https://askubuntu.com/questions/951783/how-to-find-out-who-is-taking-70-gb-of-data-from-me-each-month
#

#check that the call included the file name, and only the file name, to use.
if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
  echo "Usage - $0  file-name"
  exit 1
fi

# check that the file actually exists:
if [ ! -f $1 ]
then
  echo "tcpdump binary file $1 does not exist, aborting..."
  exit 1
fi

echo "data extraction 1: All the packets..."
# Note: Using the -e option will ease subsequent bytes per unit time calculations
sudo tcpdump -n -tttt -e -r $1 >all_e.txt

echo "data extraction 2: The outgoing normal packets..."
# Note: We might want to check that something important doesn't get missed here.
# Note: replace the fake IP address with your actual IP address.
grep ": XXX\.XXX\.XXX\.XXX\." all_e.txt | grep Flags >outgoing.txt

echo "data extraction 3: Make a histogram of the destination IP addresses by packets..."
# Note: use field 13
cut -d" " -f13 outgoing.txt | sed 's/.[^.]*$//' | sort | uniq -c | sort -g >outhisto.txt

# Phase 2: Maximum packet count might not mean maximum byte count, so figure out maximum byte count

echo "data extraction 4: Sort the outgoing file by destination IP address."
LC_ALL=C sort -k 13 <outgoing.txt >outgoing.srt

echo "data extraction 5: Now, calculate bytes per IP and bytes per IP/16 and make sorted historgrams"
# Note: There might be some clever awk or whatever way to do this, but I have a c program.
./tcpdump_bytes outgoing.srt outb.txt out16.txt
sort --general-numeric-sort <outb.txt >outhistob.txt
sort --general-numeric-sort <out16.txt >outhistob16.txt

#Leave the intermidiate files, just for now, while we debug.
#
# packet_post_process. End.
```

The c program called from within the script:

```c
    /*****************************************************************************
*
* tcpdump_bytes.c 2017.09.08 Smythies
*       By sorting the input file before running this program, it can do bytes
*       per IP all on its own, and in one pass through the file. At this time,
*       it is for outgoing only. A future revision will add command line
*       options for incoming and such.
*       Might as well group by 1st 2 IP address bytes at the same time,
*       i.e. for some (not all) of those multiple IP situations.
*
* tcpdump_bytes.c 2017.09.01 Smythies
*       Count the bytes for all the packets in the passed file.
*       See also tcpdump_extract.c, from which this was taken.
*       This program is very quite, just printing bytes, unless there
*       is some error. The idea is that is part of something bigger and
*       therefore extra verbosity would just get in the way.
*
*       Note: The input tcpdump file needs to have been done
*             with the -e option.
*
*****************************************************************************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 2000  /* maximum line length */

void main(int argc, char **argv){

   char in_buffer[MAX_LENGTH];
   char *infile, *outfile1, *outfile2;
   char *index, *index2;
   FILE *inf, *out1, *out2;
   unsigned current_bytes, sip3, sip2, sip1, sip0, sport, dip3, dip2, dip1, dip0, dport;
   unsigned dest_ip, dest_ip_16, dest_ip_old, dest_ip_16_old;
   unsigned num_lines, num_ips, num_16s;
   unsigned long long total_bytes, total_bytes_16;

   switch(argc){
   case 4:
      infile = argv[1];
      outfile1 = argv[2];
      outfile2 = argv[3];
      break;
   default:
      printf("tcpdump_bytes infile outfile1 outfile2\n");
      printf("  parse outgoing bytes per IP out of a sorted tcpdump file where the -e option was used.\n");
      printf("  infile is sorted tcpdump output file; oufile1 is bytes per IP; outfile 2 is bytes per IP/16.\n");
      exit(-1);
   } /* endcase */

   if((inf = fopen(infile, "rt")) == NULL){
      printf("Unable to open input file '%s'\n", infile);
      exit(-1);
   } /* endif */
   if((out1 = fopen(outfile1, "wt")) == NULL){
      printf("Error opening output file '%s'\n", outfile1);
      exit(-1);
   } /* endif */
   if((out2 = fopen(outfile2, "wt")) == NULL){
      printf("Error opening output file '%s'\n", outfile2);
      exit(-1);
   } /* endif */

   total_bytes = 0;
   total_bytes_16 = 0;
   dest_ip_old = 0;
   dest_ip_16_old = 0;
   num_lines = 0;
   num_ips = 0;
   num_16s = 0;

   while((fgets(in_buffer, MAX_LENGTH, inf)) != NULL){       /* do infile line at a time */
      num_lines++;

      if((index = strstr(in_buffer, "), length ")) != NULL){ /* find search string if it is there, then parse the data */
         sscanf(index, "), length %u: %u.%u.%u.%u.%u > %u.%u.%u.%u.%u:",
            &current_bytes,
            &sip3, &sip2, &sip1, &sip0,
            &sport,
            &dip3, &dip2, &dip1, &dip0,
            &dport);
      } else {
         printf("tcpdump_bytes: Got an odd line: %s", in_buffer);
      } /* endif */
      dest_ip_16 = (dip3 << 24) + (dip2 << 16);
      dest_ip = dest_ip_16 + (dip1 << 8) + dip0;
//    printf("debug: B: %u  S: %u.%u.%u.%u.%u  D: %u.%u.%u.%u.%u  %u  %u\n", current_bytes, sip3, sip2, sip1, sip0, sport, dip3, dip2, dip1, dip0, dport, dest_ip, dest_ip_16);

      if(dest_ip != dest_ip_old){
         if(total_bytes != 0){
            fprintf(out1, "%llu %u.%u.%u.%u\n", total_bytes, (dest_ip_old >> 24) & 0xff, (dest_ip_old >> 16) & 0xff, (dest_ip_old >> 8) & 0xff, dest_ip_old & 0xff);
            total_bytes = 0;
         } /* endif */
         dest_ip_old = dest_ip;
         num_ips++;
      } /* endif */
      total_bytes = total_bytes + (unsigned long long) current_bytes;

      if(dest_ip_16 != dest_ip_16_old){
         if(total_bytes_16 != 0){
            fprintf(out2, "%llu %u.%u.0.0/16\n", total_bytes_16, (dest_ip_16_old >> 24) & 0xff, (dest_ip_16_old >> 16) & 0xff);
            total_bytes_16 = 0;
         } /* endif */
         dest_ip_16_old = dest_ip_16;
         num_16s++;
      } /* endif */
      total_bytes_16 = total_bytes_16 + (unsigned long long) current_bytes;
   } /* endwhile */

   /* don't forget to output the last data */
   if(total_bytes != 0){
      fprintf(out1, "%llu %u.%u.%u.%u\n", total_bytes, dip3, dip2, dip1, dip0);
   } else {
      printf("tcpdump_bytes: Something is wrong. Last IP address has no bytes.\n");
   } /* endif */

   if(total_bytes_16 != 0){
      fprintf(out2, "%llu %u.%u.0.0/16\n", total_bytes_16, dip3, dip2);
   } else {
      printf("tcpdump_bytes: Something is wrong. Last IP/16 address has no bytes.\n");
   } /* endif */

   fclose(inf);
   fclose(out1);
   fclose(out2);
   printf("tcpdump_bytes: Done. Processed %d lines and %d IP addresses and %d /16 addresses\n", num_lines, num_ips, num_16s);
} /* endprogram */
```

Note that some files will get clobbered with the next hours processing. I'll fix that later.

A quick summary of what the post-processing script is doing:
First, the binary tcpdump file is converted to per packet summaries text. Example (my address has been changed to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX):

```
2017-05-31 08:10:31.721956 00:22:b0:75:c2:bd > 6c:be:e9:a7:f1:07, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 400: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.52779 > 38.113.165.77.443: Flags [P.], seq 1:347, ack 1, win 256, length 346
2017-05-31 08:10:31.826241 6c:be:e9:a7:f1:07 > 00:22:b0:75:c2:bd, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 157: 38.113.165.77.443 > XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.52779: Flags [P.], seq 1:104, ack 347, win 1026, length 103
2017-05-31 08:10:31.877945 00:22:b0:75:c2:bd > 6c:be:e9:a7:f1:07, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 54: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.52779 > 38.113.165.77.443: Flags [.], ack 104, win 256, length 0
2017-05-31 08:10:32.603768 00:22:b0:75:c2:bd > 6c:be:e9:a7:f1:07, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has XXX.XXX.XXX.YYY tell XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, length 28
2017-05-31 08:10:32.630960 6c:be:e9:a7:f1:07 > 00:22:b0:75:c2:bd, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 60: Reply XXX.XXX.XXX.YYY is-at 6c:be:e9:a7:f1:07, length 46
2017-05-31 08:10:33.643468 00:90:d0:63:ff:00 > 01:00:5e:00:00:01, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 60: 10.197.248.13 > 224.0.0.1: igmp query v2
2017-05-31 08:10:37.448732 00:22:b0:75:c2:bd > 6c:be:e9:a7:f1:07, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 90: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.53120 > 91.189.89.199.123: NTPv4, Client, length 48
```

It is on purpose that an ARP packet pair is included in the example, so show something that would be excluded from further processing.
The annoying IGMP packet from a private LAN IP is from my ISP and will also be excluded from further processing. However, if my ISP ever claims I have gone over my monthly data limit, I'll point to such packets when I say what I will not pay for.
Notice two lengths shown on each line, the first one is bytes on the wire and the second one is payload length. We want bytes on the wire, and this is why we use the -e option with tcpdump.

Second, outgoing packet can uniquely be identified by finding ": XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.", so extract all outgoing packets, not including ARP and ICMP, using grep.

Third, using space as a delimiter, field 13 is the destination IP address, so use a complicated bunch of piped commands to extract, count, and sort the destination IP address packets.

Forth, sort the outgoing packets by destination IP address.
Fifth, use the c program to calculate bytes per IP and bytes per IP/16 and sort the output into histograms.

Sixth, manually investigate the top IP addresses in an attempt to identify what is going on. Note that very often one can find the related forward lookup DNS inquiry in the tcpdump output.

As an example, I looked at my WAN/LAN data between 2017-05-31 08:09:33 and 2017-08-09 22:13:11 and edited in what I found for the various IP addresses.
First the top few by packet count:

```
packets IP Address      Added Comment
 299517 91.189.95.84    Ubuntu stuff
 301129 198.38.112.140  Netflix
 306815 17.253.31.206   Apple stuff
 319558 129.97.134.71   Ubuntu stuff (mirror, I think)
 333334 91.189.88.152   Ubuntu stuff
 352141 91.189.88.39    Ubuntu stuff
 353160 209.121.139.153 Telus (Microsoft updates streaming)
 368669 209.121.139.163 Telus (Microsoft updates streaming)
 389928 91.189.88.161   Ubuntu stuff
 396087 23.60.74.158    deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (?)
 421259 198.38.112.170  Netflix
 474506 17.253.31.205   Apple stuff
 477706 198.38.109.153  Netflix
 480452 198.38.112.159  Netflix
 540261 198.38.112.173  Netflix
 574592 198.38.112.132  Netflix
 710022 198.38.112.174  Netflix
 728434 209.121.139.144 Telus (Microsoft updates streaming)
 738839 198.38.112.130  Netflix
 883688 198.38.109.171  Netflix
1049778 198.38.112.154  Netflix
2166582 72.21.81.200    Hmmmm ? MCI Communications Services, (Skype, I think)
7512548 13.107.4.50     Microsoft (updates)
```

Second, the top few by byte count:

```
Bytes    IP                     Added Comment
32358580 17.253.31.205          Apple stuff
32625068 198.38.112.159         Netflix
34220805 172.217.3.206          Google web crawler
36628021 198.38.112.173         Netflix
37022702 17.188.208.132         Apple stuff
39105254 198.38.112.132         Netflix
40697177 209.121.139.144        Telus Microsoft updates file streaming
48247623 198.38.112.174         Netflix
49537980 64.4.54.254            Microsoft
50358753 198.38.112.130         Netflix
59623846 198.38.109.171         Netflix
71532166 198.38.112.154         Netflix
98480036 207.167.198.18         Telus e-mail stuff
139907010 72.21.81.200          Hmmmm ? MCI Communications Services, (Skype, I think)
210138801 91.189.95.84          Ubuntu stuff
325511064 204.79.197.213        Microsoft (?) msedge.net storage.skyprod.akadns.net
479586878 13.107.4.50           Microsoft (updates)
```

Notice how, since Netflix, for example, uses many IP addresses, it might fall lower in the ranking than it really should be, if all its IP addresses were treated as one.

Third, the top few /16 groups by bytes count. Notice how Netflix is now the biggest:

```
107592753 209.52.0.0/16         cache.google.com (for example)
116538884 207.167.0.0/16        Telus e-mail stuff
120769715 17.188.0.0/16         Apple. store-025-failover2.blobstore-apple.com.akadns.net (for example)
139261655 52.218.0.0/16         s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com (for example) ? Hmmm...
147091123 172.217.0.0/16        Google web crawler
153146532 17.248.0.0/16         p46-keyvalueservice.fe.apple-dns.net. Apple iCloud Drive
183300509 72.21.0.0/16          Skype (I think)
213119564 209.121.0.0/16        Telus Microsoft updates file streaming
333374588 204.79.0.0/16         Microsoft
354346088 91.189.0.0/16         Ubuntu stuff
488793579 13.107.0.0/16         Microsoft (updates)
621733032 198.38.0.0/16         Netflix
```

Comment: `/bin/dash` should be `/bin/bash` probably? Along the same vein 2017.08.01 should be 2017.09.01?  I haven't used C in 20 years and am not sure how outgoing packets and IP addresses are being captured.  But I was thinking perhaps MySQL would be the right method for logging a years worth of traffic? I'm pricing out some 3 TB hdds for my laptop 2nd bay today.  I'm hoping a database can give the name linked to the IP address rather than manually typing it in. Maybe there is a whois command somewhere? I figured out the offending website using `vnstat -l` command: rt.com/on-the-air (Russians....).

Comment: Nope, I tend to use dash. Date, yes, thanks. I am doing my big data now, but doing the top 5000, instead of 100. It will take at least overnight, and I even moved the data to my much much much more powerful test server, and the entire 10Gig outgoing file is cached in memory. I don't know about MySQL.

Comment: Oh never heard of dash, obviously a bash derivative. The 10 GB outgoing file in RAM must include every byte sent in the day? I was only thinking of logging IP addresses and total bytes not every byte! Besides there is only 8 GB RAM on laptop and it's only possible to upgrade to 16 GB on Ivy Bridge. Could log to SSD though have 300 GB unused.  Learning SQL is on my to-do list for big business arena. I also want to get back into C again (it's been 20 years) which makes your project even more enticing.

Comment: I notice Microsoft Updates has the largest number of packets. Does this mean your Linux program is running in a virtual box within Windows and can monitor how much internet traffic Windows applications are consuming? I'm only asking because I would like `vnstat` to monitor internet bandwidth consumed when I've dual booted into Windows 8.1.

Comment: My data is from my main gateway router/firewall Ubuntu server between the WAN and my LAN. Those MS update packets are for various windows computers on my LAN. It is just that the packets flow through my Ubuntu server/ router.

Comment: I think your answer is superior in tracking IP addresses as opposed to simple website name.

Comment: Happy to say this problem has been fixed. I updated my answer with Edit 5.

Answer (score 2):

## Problem persists January 7, 2018 in Firefox

*skip to bottom, **"Edit 6"** to see Firefox only problem*

## Problem solved December 13, 2017

*skip to bottom, **"Edit 5"** to see Chrome solution*

## Answering 4 of the 5 W's

I was able to isolate Who, What, Where and When data is being uploaded:

- **Who** = rt.com / on-the-air.
- **What** = Flashplayer plug-in
- **Where** = in Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox
- **When** = Morning and Evenings when I watch international news

The "Why" could be a bug or it could be spyware or it could simply be Flashplayer has been configured to collect information streams for crash reporting purposes.

The next section details the steps to isolate Who, What, Where and When.

## Use `vnstat -l` to track upload traffic

Apologies in advance for screen images below rather than text copy and paste. I had taken snapshots not knowing if the information was relevant until after all tests were done.

The first step in testing is to close down all 10 Chrome tabs and 3 Firefox tabs.

Next open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and type `vnstat -l`. This assumes you have already installed the vnstat command. If not, see this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103634/any-good-application-for-data-usage-monitor/851703#851703) about `vnstat` in Ask Ubuntu.

Then open up one Chrome or Firefox tab at a time and monitor the usage rates:

### Watching 80 minute documentary on lead singer/producer from ELO:

[image: vnstat -l 720p movie putlockerhd.png]

Content is in 720p format. One Gigabyte downloaded and 40 Megabytes uploaded is a 4% tx to rx ratio and appears normal.

### Watching 5 minute live news broadcast in Flashplayer format using Google Chrome:

[image: vnstat chrome flash player rt on air.png]

Content is in 1080p format. 103.37 MiB was downloaded which is normal but almost twice that amount (192.62 MiB = 186%) was uploaded which is **not normal**.

### Watching 30 minutes of recorded news downloadable from same international news broadcaster:

[image: vnstat -l rt.com-shows rt america.png]

I paused the 1/2 hour pre-recorded downloadable broadcast many times while it was playing. Elapsed time was actually 72 minutes. Nonetheless total downloads (they are recorded at 720p) is 508.12 MiB and uploads are 21.63 MiB for a tx to rx ratio of 4%.

## Summary

Unless you are a software developer constantly uploading to `github` or a freelance graphic artist constantly uploading your work to clients, the normal tx to rx ratio should be about **4%**.

In this case the monthly internet accounting was 275.79 GiB downloaded and 70.54 GiB uploaded for a tx/rx ratio of **26%**. The culprit was Flashplayer live news broadcast where the tx/rx ratio is **186%**!

The paranoid pandas living in the bamboo forests around us might think the  CIA or NSA is behind these large uploads. I think it is just a design flaw in FlashPlayer.

It could perhaps be the Russian broadcaster (RT) based in Moscow using Israeli software with glitches. I say this because I previously discovered a glitch on their news website where the comment section would [eat up 1 GB of RAM in a few hours](https://askubuntu.com/questions/845013/whats-eating-all-the-ram-and-swap/845020#845020) until the tab was refreshed. Unfortunately my original Q&A appears to have been deleted but after posting my original Q&A here in AU someone read it and fixed that problem. Hopefully similar people will find this thread and fix this problem too.

This is important because as consumers we are paying to **watch** media. We are not paying to have what we watch **uploaded at twice the bandwidth** to "only Google knows where".

---

## Edit - Tests under Kernel 4.12.10

Previous tests were conducted under kernel `4.4.0-93`. I fresh installed kernel `4.12.10` and rebooted a couple of times and conducted new tests. For both Firefox and Chrome the results are greatly improved but still tx/rx ratios are unacceptable.

- Firefox for 5.33 minutes has 108.04 MiB downloaded and 57.71 MiB uploaded for tx/rx ratio of **53.4%**
- Chrome for 5.57 minutes has 117.34 MiB downloaded and 59.75 MiB uploaded for a tx/rx ratio of **50.9%**

Data collected show below. In light of these results I will redo `4.4.0-93` tests after rebooting a couple of times.

### Firefox Flashplayer 5 minutes live news at 1080p:

```
rick@dell:~$ vnstat -l
Monitoring eth0...    (press CTRL-C to stop)

   rx:        1 kbit/s     1 p/s          tx:        1 kbit/s     1 p/s^C


 eth0  /  traffic statistics

                           rx         |       tx
--------------------------------------+------------------
  bytes                   108.04 MiB  |       57.71 MiB
--------------------------------------+------------------
          max           14.72 Mbit/s  |    10.64 Mbit/s
      average            2.77 Mbit/s  |     1.48 Mbit/s
          min               0 kbit/s  |        0 kbit/s
--------------------------------------+------------------
  packets                     133538  |          104640
--------------------------------------+------------------
          max               1395 p/s  |        1219 p/s
      average                417 p/s  |         327 p/s
          min                  0 p/s  |           0 p/s
--------------------------------------+------------------
  time                  5.33 minutes
```

### Chrome Flashplayer 5 minutes live news at 1080p:

```
rick@dell:~$ vnstat -l
Monitoring eth0...    (press CTRL-C to stop)

   rx:        0 kbit/s     0 p/s          tx:        0 kbit/s     0 p/s^C


 eth0  /  traffic statistics

                           rx         |       tx
--------------------------------------+------------------
  bytes                   117.34 MiB  |       59.75 MiB
--------------------------------------+------------------
          max           25.13 Mbit/s  |     9.92 Mbit/s
      average            2.88 Mbit/s  |     1.47 Mbit/s
          min               0 kbit/s  |        0 kbit/s
--------------------------------------+------------------
  packets                     139174  |          126372
--------------------------------------+------------------
          max               2363 p/s  |        1441 p/s
      average                416 p/s  |         378 p/s
          min                  0 p/s  |           0 p/s
--------------------------------------+------------------
  time                  5.57 minutes
```

## Edit 2 - Things get worse the more tabs you have open

I was a little premature with my kernel version `4.12.10` hypothesis. Doing further investigation watching a Flashplayer live broadcast in Chrome with 6 tabs open the tx/rx ratio got much worse. I have to surmise that somehow Flashplayer is gathering and transmitting data for other tabs other than it's own.

### Chrome 26 minute Flashplayer live broadcast with 5 other tabs open:

```
rick@dell:~$ vnstat -l
Monitoring eth0...    (press CTRL-C to stop)

   rx:        1 kbit/s     1 p/s          tx:        1 kbit/s     1 p/s^C


 eth0  /  traffic statistics

                           rx         |       tx
--------------------------------------+------------------
  bytes                   718.79 MiB  |        1.13 GiB
--------------------------------------+------------------
          max           30.10 Mbit/s  |    12.72 Mbit/s
      average            3.73 Mbit/s  |     6.00 Mbit/s
          min               0 kbit/s  |        0 kbit/s
--------------------------------------+------------------
  packets                    1100634  |         1396530
--------------------------------------+------------------
          max               2616 p/s  |        1774 p/s
      average                696 p/s  |         883 p/s
          min                  0 p/s  |           0 p/s
--------------------------------------+------------------
  time                 26.33 minutes
```

As can be expected at 1080p the total download is 718.79 MiB. What is shocking is the 1.13 GiB uploaded! This gives a tx/rx ratio of **157%**. This leads me to conclude my test results from 2 days ago and those screen snapshots had my usual 10 Chrome tabs and 3 Firefox tabs open.

The next test will be 7 tabs open and doing normal surfing / Ask Ubuntu questions and answers for 1/2 hour and get non-Flashplayer totals only.

## Edit 3 - Using conky to monitor in real time

First the test results of 7 taps open answering a Ubuntu question (the one above):

```
rick@dell:~$ vnstat -l
Monitoring eth0...    (press CTRL-C to stop)

   rx:        1 kbit/s     1 p/s          tx:        2 kbit/s     3 p/s^C


 eth0  /  traffic statistics

                           rx         |       tx
--------------------------------------+------------------
  bytes                     1.14 MiB  |         454 KiB
--------------------------------------+------------------
          max            2.40 Mbit/s  |      136 kbit/s
      average            9.35 kbit/s  |     3.64 kbit/s
          min               0 kbit/s  |        0 kbit/s
--------------------------------------+------------------
  packets                       3699  |            2776
--------------------------------------+------------------
          max                257 p/s  |         163 p/s
      average                  3 p/s  |           2 p/s
          min                  0 p/s  |           0 p/s
--------------------------------------+------------------
  time                 16.63 minutes
```

Next a test with 7 tabs open doing nothing for 1/2 hour on the machine:

```
rick@dell:~$ vnstat -l
Monitoring eth0...    (press CTRL-C to stop)

   rx:        1 kbit/s     1 p/s          tx:        2 kbit/s     2 p/s^C


 eth0  /  traffic statistics

                           rx         |       tx
--------------------------------------+------------------
  bytes                      766 KiB  |         529 KiB
--------------------------------------+------------------
          max             121 kbit/s  |      164 kbit/s
      average            3.33 kbit/s  |     2.30 kbit/s
          min               0 kbit/s  |        0 kbit/s
--------------------------------------+------------------
  packets                       4752  |            3772
--------------------------------------+------------------
          max                256 p/s  |          24 p/s
      average                  2 p/s  |           2 p/s
          min                  0 p/s  |           0 p/s
--------------------------------------+------------------
  time                 30.70 minutes
```

So we can see even when nothing is happening on your machine it's normal for Chrome to transmit packets but the size is small (529 KiB or so).

### Conky text

I added this conky text to monitor network real time usage:

```
${color1}Network real-time monitoring
${color}Down: ${color green}${downspeed eth0}/s ${color}${goto 220}Up: ${color green}${upspeed eth0}/s
${downspeedgraph eth0 25,190 000000 ff0000} ${alignr}${upspeedgraph eth0
25,190 000000 00ff00}$color
Total: ${color green}${totaldown eth0} $color${alignr}Total: ${color green}${totalup eth0}
${color orange}${voffset 2}${hr 1}
```

### Conky display

[image: conky network real time 4.gif]

The totals at the bottom are since the last boot, not since conky was turned on.

## Edit 4 - HTML5 doesn't upload like Flashplayer does

I ran a 27.5 minute test under Kernel 4.12.10 of a youtube.com live news channel (with 4 hour time shift) at 1080p:

```
rick@dell:~$ vnstat -l
Monitoring eth0...    (press CTRL-C to stop)

   rx:       12 kbit/s     4 p/s          tx:        3 kbit/s     2 p/s^C


 eth0  /  traffic statistics

                           rx         |       tx
--------------------------------------+------------------
  bytes                   474.04 MiB  |       19.49 MiB
--------------------------------------+------------------
          max           17.27 Mbit/s  |     2.16 Mbit/s
      average            2.35 Mbit/s  |    96.76 kbit/s
          min               0 kbit/s  |        0 kbit/s
--------------------------------------+------------------
  packets                     346609  |          198883
--------------------------------------+------------------
          max               1481 p/s  |        1047 p/s
      average                210 p/s  |         120 p/s
          min                  0 p/s  |           0 p/s
--------------------------------------+------------------
  time                 27.50 minutes
```

474.04 MiB were downloaded and 19.49 MiB were uploaded giving the average tx/rx ratio of **4%**. This test was done using Chrome browser but I expect the Firefox browser results would be the same. Therefore it's safe to assume the massive data uploads are limited to Flashplayer and not HTML5.

Hopefully other users can test to confirm my findings and comment below.

In the meantime I've being holding discussions with Doug Smythies (who posted the other answer here) in the Ask Ubuntu General Chat Room about his solution. Using Doug's answer I hope to discover the physical IP addresses my data is going to.

---

## Edit 5 - Dec 13 2017 - Problem solved Kernel 4.14.4

In the last couple of days the problem has gone away on it's own. Likely a Flashplayer update or kernel update:

- Upload rate is now 8.33 MiB / 224.78 MiB = 4%
- Chrome bug of taking ~5 seconds to maximize screen is fixed
- Chrome bug of image being ~1 second behind voice is fixed

### vnstat -l results

```
 enp59s0  /  traffic statistics

                           rx         |       tx
--------------------------------------+------------------
  bytes                   224.78 MiB  |        8.33 MiB
--------------------------------------+------------------
          max           10.26 Mbit/s  |      799 kbit/s
      average            2.48 Mbit/s  |    92.00 kbit/s
          min               2 kbit/s  |        4 kbit/s
--------------------------------------+------------------
  packets                     162124  |           95039
--------------------------------------+------------------
          max                886 p/s  |         408 p/s
      average                218 p/s  |         128 p/s
          min                  1 p/s  |           1 p/s
--------------------------------------+------------------
  time                 12.37 minutes
```

**Note:** Last month I got a new laptop where the problem persisted. However in the last couple of days the problem went away on it's own either from a Chrome update *Version 63.0.3239.84 (Official Build) (64-bit)* and/or because *Kernel 4.14.4* is being used.

---

## Edit 6 - Jan 07 2018 - Problem persists Firefox version 57.0.4

In the last couple of days I had problems using Chrome so started using Firefox full time. I also installed kernel `4.14.12` to test Meltdown kernel patches:

- Upload rate is now 254.76 MiB / 364.83 MiB = 70%
- Chrome bug of taking ~5 seconds to maximize screen came back

### vnstat -l results

```
 enp59s0  /  traffic statistics

                           rx         |       tx
--------------------------------------+------------------
  bytes                   364.83 MiB  |      254.76 MiB
--------------------------------------+------------------
          max           15.23 Mbit/s  |     9.88 Mbit/s
      average            3.58 Mbit/s  |     2.50 Mbit/s
          min             195 kbit/s  |      100 kbit/s
--------------------------------------+------------------
  packets                     429358  |          364510
--------------------------------------+------------------
          max               1450 p/s  |        1229 p/s
      average                513 p/s  |         436 p/s
          min                147 p/s  |          94 p/s
--------------------------------------+------------------
  time                 13.93 minutes
```

So.... full circle :(